# Parsear variable antes de mapear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsear

tengo esta particularidad
una colección de objetos que se guarda en una variable `MUO_str.aah`, y tengo otra variable que tiene el nombre de la colección que quiero usar,

la idea es usar la colección general `MUO_str.aah`y luego parsear el valor de la variable en la que se guarda un nombre especifico de colección, ejemplo 'libros'
de forma que se reconozca y se mapee, pero salta error,

lo intente así:

```
MUO_str.aah.$MUO_str.aac[0].bakd.map((m, i) =>( ...
```

y también así:

```
  MUO_str.aah.$(MUO_str.aac[0].bakd).map((m, i) =>( ...
```

a alguien se le ocurre alguna solución? ayuda porfavor.

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que quieres hacer. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo válido usando ese nombre (libros) para acceder a un dato concreto?

Comment: MUO_str.aah, es un opjeto tiene mucho parametros en su interior ejmplo 
{libros: {a,b,c....}, articulos : {a,b,c},..... }  lo deseo  mapear solo la colección de libros o artículos según conveniencia, usando una variable que tiene esa ruta,
ejemplo 2. MUO_str.aah.libros.map (..... 
pero usando la variable MUO_str.aac[0].bakd, de forma que quede así 
  MUO_str.aah.$(MUO_str.aac[0].bakd).map(...
no se como explicarlo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO

mi problema se detalla como sigue:

MUO_str.aah, es un objeto tiene mucho parámetros en su interior y estos a su vez son objetos también,  ejemplo {libros: {a,b,c....}, articulos : {a,b,c},..... } se desea mapear solo la colección de libros o artículos según conveniencia, usando una variable que tiene el nombre del parámetro,

realizado en forma tradicional seria: MUO_str.aah.libros.map(( ....

pero ahora se usara la variable MUO_str.aac[0].bakd
De forma que quede así: MUO_str.aah.[''+ MUO_str.aac[0].bakd+''].map(...

de esta forma modificando el valor de la variable MUO_str.aac[0].bakd,
se iterara entre uno y otro parámetro de objetos que tiene MUO_str.aah,

De nada....

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Puede que para ti sea claro, pero para otros quienes lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer].